# What is 「おけなかった」in this sentence? 『風紀を乱しまくる私たちを 野放しにしておけなかったんだ』

Tags: grammar, conjugations

I came across this sentence in a show I was watching and I have no idea what to make of it

> 風紀を乱しまくる私たちを 野放しにしておけなかったんだ

What is 「おけなかった」in this sentence?

Comment: Related: [What does おけない mean in the following sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70609/43676)

Answer (score 1):

It's the potential verb of おく, "to leave"
私たちを野放しにしておけなかった could not leave us running loose (doing as we please).

Answer (score 1):

野放し: uncontrolled
野放し に して おく: basic sentence (leave uncontrolled)
野放し に して おける : + can, be able to
野放し に して おけ ない: + not
野放し に して おけ な かった: + past